# this.init not a function

Tags: javascript, constructor, initialization

I'm doing this for class and the test they have says my constructor is not being initialized so I looked that up and found `this.init()`.  Now I am getting "this.init() is not a function and I am not sure why.

My code:

```
function CuboidMaker(length, width, height){
  const volume = () => {
    return this.length * this.width * this.height
  }

  const surfaceArea = () => {
    return 2 * (this.length * this.width + this.length * this.height + this.width * this.height)
  }

  this.length = length
  this.width = width
  this.height = height
  this.volume = volume
  this.surfaceArea = surfaceArea
  this.init()
}
```

Comment: Well, it means there's no `init` function on the object or its prototype.

Comment: why do you expect `this.init()` to work when you haven't defined an `init` property anywhere? Your code looks fine to me if you simply remove this, so what motivated you to add it?

Comment: The test failing saying it could initialize the constructor.  After googling how to do that, I came a cross init()

Comment: why u use "function CuboidMaker ()"and not "class CuboidMaker{}". In addition, if you "doing this for a class" call a constructor at the beginig of you're class.

Answer (score 0):

Is it simply that you're not creating a new instance of the constructor?

Also, `volume` and `surfaceArea` are both functions and need to be called.

```js
function CuboidMaker(length, width, height){

  const volume = () => {
    return this.length * this.width * this.height;
  }

  const surfaceArea = () => {
    return 2 * (this.length * this.width + this.length * this.height + this.width * this.height);
  }

  this.length = length;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.volume = volume();
  this.surfaceArea = surfaceArea();

}

const a = new CuboidMaker(1, 2, 3);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't initialize you're class correctly. Try this syntax :

```js
class CuboidMaker{
        constructor(length, width, height){
            this.length = length;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }
        volume(){
          return this.length * this.width * this.height
        }
        surfaceArea(){
                return 2 * (this.length * this.width + this.length * this.height + this.width * this.height)
        }
    }
    
    let myCuboid = new CuboidMaker(1, 2, 3);
    console.log(myCuboid.volume());
    console.log(myCuboid.surfaceArea());
```